# An equation with floor function

Tags: real-analysis

I wante to solve an equation of the form

$$⌊x⌋=2⌊y+1⌋$$

with respect to $x$ and $y$, i.e., finding regions for $x$ and $y$ without using the symbol of the floor function $⌊.⌋$

Comment: Could you say what you mean by "not using the floor function"?

Comment: @Med: I mean finding the region without using the symbol of the floor function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be an integer. When $n\le y<n+1$, $2\lfloor y+1\rfloor=2(n+1)$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor=2(n+1)$ $\implies$ $2(n+1)\le x<2n+3$. This gives a series of rectangular regions. For example, when $n=0$, we have the rectangular region
$$\{(x,y):2\le x<3, 0\le y<1\}$$

Answer (score 3):

You can substitute the floor function with its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties) and use the property that $\lfloor y+1\rfloor=\lfloor y\rfloor+1$ , so you can write something as:
$$
2 \cdot\mbox{max}\{m\in \mathbb{Z},m\le y\}+1 \le x< 2\cdot\mbox{max}\{m\in \mathbb{Z},m\le y\}+3 
$$